# awk alter the next line after a pattern match based on another pattern match

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with lines such as:

```
....
pattern1 100 200 300
pattern2 300 400 400
pattern1 300 900 700
pattern1 200 500 900
...
```

As shown in the above example, there are some lines where `pattern2` follows `pattern1` but not all. I would like to match `pattern1` then check if the next line has `pattern2` and if it does, alter the next number field by multiplying it with a constant factor. I tried using `getline` with `awk` but it erases the lines with `pattern1` from the resulting output:

```
awk '/pattern1/{getline; if($1==pattern2) $(NF-2)*=0.889848406214}1' infile.dat
```

Any suggestions how can I accomplish this without altering anything else in the input file.

Comment: How big are your files? Are you open to solutions that would load the entire file into memory? Are you open to non-awk solutions? Are there more than two patterns? Can you have `pattern45` as well?

Comment: Files are medium sized, nothing too big. However, I would prefer `awk` solution because there is other processing done on the file which is done via `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
  /pattern1/ { f = 1; print; next }
  f && /pattern2/ { $(NF-2) *= 0.889848406214 }
  { f = 0; print }
' <file
```

Comment: `/pattern2/&&f{$(NF-2)*=0.889848406214}{print;f=0}/pattern1/{f=1}`

Comment: @Costas: Cool, a little shorter.

Comment: Can you explain each line please?

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is failing because `getline` immediately moves to the next line so the current one is lost. A simple solution would be to save the current line in a variable and *then* move to the next:

```
$ awk '{
        if(/pattern1/){
            l=$0; 
            getline; 
            if($1=="pattern2"){
                $(NF-2)*=0.889848406214
            } 
            print l"\n"$0
        }
        else{print}
       }' file
pattern1 100 200 300
pattern2 266.955 400 400
pattern1 300 900 700
pattern1 200 500 900
```

Alternatively, use a flag that keeps track of whether the previous line matched `pattern1`:

```
$ awk '{if(/pattern2/ && l){$(NF-2)*=0.889848406214} /pattern1/ ? l=1 : l=0;}1;' file
pattern1 100 200 300
pattern2 266.955 400 400
pattern1 300 900 700
pattern1 200 500 900
```