# Awk: Alter lines depending on the next one

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I use awk to modify lines that match a certain pattern, but only if the NEXT line does not match another pattern?

For example take this fragment:

```
....
pattern1 100 200 300
pattern1 300 400 400
pattern2 300 900 700
pattern1 200 500 900
...
```

I would like to modify all lines containing `pattern1`, except for the second one which is followed by a line containing `pattern2`.

This is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258320/awk-alter-the-next-line-after-a-pattern-match-based-on-another-pattern-match), but just the other way around.

Comment: Modify how? Depending on the constraints, you could save the previous line and modify it in the next line's iteration

Comment: I need to replace a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I needed:

```
/pattern1/ {
    if (candidate) {
        print "modify:", candidate
    }
    candidate=$0
    next
}

/pattern2/ {
    if (candidate) {
        print candidate
        candidate=0
    }
}

{
    if (candidate) {
        print "modify:", candidate
        candidate=0
    }
    print $0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
/pattern2/ { print intact ; print $0 ; next ;}
! /pattern2/  { print new ;}
{ intact=$0 ; $1="p1" ; new=$0 ; }
```

there is an extra empty line

result is

```
p1 100 200 300
pattern1 300 400 400
pattern2 300 900 700
p1 300 400 400
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   /pattern1/!b
   $q; N
   /\npattern2/!s/^/MODIFIED:/
   P;D
' yourfile

perl -0777pe 's/(?=pattern1.*$)(?!pattern2)/MODIFIED:/gm' yourfile
```

Comment: I am asking specifically about awk.